# Does Death by the spell Immolate cause all items held/worn to be destroyed?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, wizard

In a recent session, my Wizard cast immolate on an opposing wizard and did enough damage to kill the already damaged target of the spell. By the spell's own description, "If damage from this spell kills a target, the target is turned to ash". It doesn't say anything about carried items the way that disintegrate does. My DM ruled that all the items including the wizard's spell book, item bag, scroll case and Wand (undetermined contents and type) were destroyed in the ensuing fire. I attempted to argue that carried items weren't listed as being destroyed specifically like the disintegrate spell, but I let up since DM's have final say in ruling situations.

I would like to know the general consensus on the wording as to whether the items should have been destroyed or not just for future games or future situations where this may come up as a problem again.

Answer (score 4):

#### It’s up to the DM. Magic items are less likely to be destroyed, but again subject to DM ruling.

So on the one hand, the following situation makes little sense to me:

> Succumbing to the flames of your *immolation* spell, the priest crumbles to ash, leaving behind his total mundane cloth robes, untouched by the flames.

The spell isn’t specific here, so it’s going to be up to the DM what burns and what doesn’t. That said, magical items have particular resilience (from the DMG section “Magic Item Resilience”):

> Most magic items are objects of extraordinary artisanship, assembled from the finest materials with meticulous attention to detail. Thanks to this combination of careful crafting and magical reinforcement, a magic item is at least as durable as a regular item of its kind. Most magic items, other than potions and scrolls, have resistance to all damage. Artifacts are practically indestructible, requiring extreme measures to destroy.

So a magical item is at least more likely to survive than a mundane item of similar construction. Again, up to the DM.

I’d say your DM’s ruling is within the rules as written, as the rules are somewhat non-specific, but I personally would have ruled that magic items would persist through the flames.